# How can I check if a user is using disconnect.me / blocking mixpanel

Tags: javascript, mixpanel

I have a webapp - I use google analytics and mixpanel for tacking.

Lately some users have registered but aren't appearing in mixpanel.
I want to see if these users are blocking mixpanel / using disconnect.me.

If I use Disconnect.me myself, Chrome shows an error in the console but it is async to my

> mixpanel.track

The error is appearing from (index):1 with no stacktrace

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.mixpanel.com/engage/?data=eyIkcIjogeyIkbiTGludXgiLCIkY…2YiLCIkZGlY3RfaWQiOiAiY2hlb0YWtpcGkuY29n0%3D&ip=1&_=1396192302485. The request was redirected to a URL ('about:blank') which has a disallowed scheme for cross-origin requests.
```

so I can't catch it.

What Javascript code can I use to answer "is mixpanel connected?"

Answer (score 1):

You could simply emit a track event or something else and see if you get a response for mixpanel. Their [HTTP spec](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/http) shows what they respond. If you get a success you're connected.
Another solution that might fit you better though would be to proxy all mixpanel events. You simply send them from the JS lib via your server. I don't think disconnect will block that since it'll look like normal async requests to you server.